# Carousel (slider) with flexbox and react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to do a Carousel (alias Slider) with flexbox and React (no JQuery, libraries nor DOM manipulation).

In order to re-order the items, I'm using the property `order` of flexbox. However, this property doesn't support any transition effect, so in order to do the effect I'm trying to do the same thing that this article explain: https://blog.envylabs.com/the-order-property-flexbox-carousels-87a168567820 (using `transform`)

Nevertheless, I'm getting a lot of issues with responsiveness, different steps (example move 3 slides to 3 instead of just one), transition effect...

I would appreciate it if someone can help me in order to solve this buggy things ... I have now a headache after a lot of time ...

I added my code in stackblitz:

- **Editor**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/carousel-pov
- **App**: https://carousel-pov.stackblitz.io

Also I add here the code:

**carousel.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import './carousel.scss'

const STEP = 1

export default class Carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.next = this.next.bind(this)
    this.prev = this.prev.bind(this)
    this.resetSet = this.resetSet.bind(this)
    this.state = { ref: 0, isSet: true, isReversing: false }
  }

  getOrder(index) {
    const { items } = this.props
    const { ref } = this.state
    const order = index - ref

    if (order >= 0) {
      return order
    }

    return items.length - order
  }

  resetSet() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isSet: true })
    }, 50)
  }

  next() {
    const { ref } = this.state
    const { items } = this.props
    const newRef = ref + STEP

    if (newRef < items.length) {
      this.setState({
        ref: newRef,
        isSet: false,
        isReversing: false,
      }, this.resetSet)
    }
  }

  prev() {
    const { ref } = this.state
    const newRef = ref - STEP

    if (newRef >= 0) {
      this.setState({
        ref: newRef,
        isSet: false,
        isReversing: true,
      }, this.resetSet)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { title, items } = this.props
    const { isSet, isReversing } = this.state
    const classSet = isSet ? 'is-set' : ''
    const classReversing = isReversing ? 'is-reversing' : ''

    return (
      <>
        {title && <h2 className="carousel-title">{title}</h2>}
        <div className="carousel-wrapper" role="listbox">
          <div
            role="button"
            onClick={this.prev}
            tabIndex={0}
            className="arrow"
          >
          ⬅️
          </div>
          <div className={`carousel ${classSet} ${classReversing}`}>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
              <div
                key={item}
                style={{ order: this.getOrder(index) }}
                className="item"
              >{item}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div
            className="arrow"
            role="button"
            onClick={this.next}
            tabIndex={0}
          >
          ➡️
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

**carousel.scss**

```
.carousel-title {
  font-family: 'PT_Serif-Web-BoldItalic';
  font-size: 20px;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;

  &:before,
  &:after {
      content: '';
      border-top: 1px solid;
  }
}

.carousel-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  .widget {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  .arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 40px;
  }

  .carousel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 750px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateX(100%);

    &.is-reversing {
      transform: translateX(-100%)
    }

    &.is-set {
      transform: none;
      transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    }

    @media(max-width: 1049px){
      width: 500px;
    }
    @media(max-width: 800px){
      width: 240px;
    }
  }
}

.item {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 230px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px
}

body {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Example of use:

- `<Carousel title="My carousel" items={[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]} />`

Thank you so much to help me!

Comment: Nice work till now, I'm checking this to see if I can help ;)

Comment: @DanielVafidis I appreciate this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Okay

So here's what I've found:

1st: You transition on 100%: so if show 3 items, all three items will slide, I've managed to handle this by hand, changing 100% to 250px (there may be a better way but that's the idea).

```
transform: translateX(250px);

&.is-reversing {
  transform: translateX(250px)
}
```

Second: your getOrder did return

```
items.length - order
```

instead of

```
items.length + order
```

like this

```
getOrder(index) {
    const { items } = this.props
    const { ref } = this.state
    const order = index - ref

    if (order >= 0) {
      return order;
    }
    else{
        return items.length + order;
    }

}
```

Then for the slides, NEXT didn't have a result for when the ref was higher than items.length

```
if (newRef <= items.length) {
  this.setState({
    ref: newRef,
    isSet: false,
    isReversing: false,
  }, this.resetSet)
}else{
  this.setState(
    {
      ref: 1,
      isSet: false,
      isReversing: false
    },
    this.resetSet
  );
}
```

and yor slide PREV should work like this

```
if (newRef >= 0) {
  this.setState({
    ref: newRef,
    isSet: false,
    isReversing: true,
  }, this.resetSet)
}else{
  this.setState(
    {
      ref: 8,
      isSet: false,
      isReversing: true
    },
    this.resetSet
  );
}
```

as you can see I've added some stuff like 250px and "8" that maybe be added like 250px is the item width and the 8 is last index of the array.

also I've realized that your transition always slides left. I can look further as soon as I have time but for now that's what I managed to do,

I hope it helps, Not sure if I did explain well but I tried my best.

have fun

https://stackblitz.com/edit/carousel-pov-rvftku

Edit: added a carousel fork on stackblitz